# numpy histogram with 3 variables

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, heatmap

Please forgive me if this is a repeated question, I've done my best to look for a solution.  This seems very straightforward but I can't seem to find anything applicable.

I'm trying to generate a plot (like a heatmap) using data from 3 1-D numpy arrays.  The data is basically arranged as follows:

```
x_axis = ([1, 4, 6])
y_axis = ([2, 5, 7])
z_axis = ([5, 8, 9])
```

(my data sets are actually much larger... sometimes hundreds of thousands of entries).

so I've got z_axis values that are each associated with an x-coordinate and y-coordinate... for example, the point (1,2) has the value 5 associated with it.

All I want to do is plot this in such a way that the z values are averaged out for whatever bin size I specify, and color-coded like a heatmap.   So, for instance, if I've got 10 data points that fall within a given bin, their z-values will be averaged and that value will fall somewhere on a color spectrum.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [np.histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
H, xedges, yedges =np.histogram2d(x_axis, y_axis, bins=10, weights=z_axis) 
extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[-1], xedges[0]]
plt.imshow(H, extent=extent, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Bin count is easily changed.

As Jamie pointed out in the comments if you want the average of the points in each bin:

```
numbins=10
H, xedges, yedges =np.histogram2d(x_axis, y_axis, bins=numbins, weights=z_axis) 
count, x, y =np.histogram2d(x_axis, y_axis, bins=numbins) 
H/=count
```

Comment: If he wants averages, not sums, you'll have to run `np.histogram2d` again without the `weights` keyword argument to get counts in each bin, and plot the division of both arrays.

Comment: Thats a good point, I wasn't quite reading the question that way. I thought he was phrasing it as the array should be normalized for the colors, but plt doesnt care either way.